# Cannot get Typeahead value

Tags: reactjs, typeahead

I'm trying to create a tag input typeahead from this library:

```
import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
```

in my reactjs app:

```
<Typeahead
    allowNew
    id="custom-selections-example"
    multiple
    newSelectionPrefix="Add a new item: "
    options={opt}
    placeholder="Autocomplete"
    name="tags"
    onChange={onChange}

    value={values.options}
    />
```

the statement **console.log(values.options)**-> does not return anything when I select one of the options...

Can someone show me a way to get the value?

**UPDATE**
I have previously tested with onChange function and gives the following error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
```

**OnChange Method:**

```
const { values, onChange, onSubmit } = useForm(createPostCallback, {
        tags:''
    })
 const [createData, { error }] = useMutation(CREATE_QUERY, {
    variables: values,...code continues
```

Comment: There is no console.log in your snippet code

Comment: You are missing onChange event.

Comment: @Sam it gives me this error if I add onChange:`TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: @buzatto there is at the top of the code

Comment: @BruceWayne Can you please put your onChange code?

Comment: @BruceWayne I added an answer for you, with the console.log at the onChange event. Value returns an array, you need to filter for a single element([0]) if you have the single selection.

Comment: @buzatto the onchange method is on the question...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the documentation:

```
<Typeahead
    allowNew
    id="id"
    multiple
    newSelectionPrefix="Add a new item: "
    options={opts}
    placeholder="Autocomplete tags"
    onChange={(selected) => { values.tags = selected  }}   />
```

The typeahead behaves similarly to other form elements. It requires an array of data options to be filtered and displayed.

```
<Typeahead
  onChange={(selected) => {
    // Handle selections...
  }}
  options={[ /* Array of objects or strings */ ]}
/>
```

Comment: How do you get event inside onChange field?. As per you you have a common method which accepts the event and update state.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the working code . https://codesandbox.io/s/wonderful-sanderson-eg0g8?file=/src/index.js:0-648. Here I modified the code based on your requirement, now you can call your parent onChange method from the `handleChange` method.

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef, useState } from 'react';
import { Typeahead } from 'react-bootstrap-typeahead';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';

import options from './data';

import 'react-bootstrap-typeahead/css/Typeahead.css';
import './styles.css';

const TypeaheadExample = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = useState([]);

  const refHidden = useRef(null);

  const onChange = (name) => (values) => {
    if (values.length > 0) {
      const e = new Event('input', { bubbles: true });
      setNativeValue(refHidden.current, values[0].capital);
      refHidden.current.dispatchEvent(e);
    }
  };
  function setNativeValue(element, value) {
    const valueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(element, 'value').set;
    const prototype = Object.getPrototypeOf(element);
    const prototypeValueSetter = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(
      prototype,
      'value'
    ).set;

    if (valueSetter && valueSetter !== prototypeValueSetter) {
      prototypeValueSetter.call(element, value);
    } else {
      valueSetter.call(element, value);
    }
  }
  function handleChange(e) {
    console.log(e.target.name);
    console.log(e.target.value);
  }
  //{(text, e) => { console.log(text, e); }}
  return (
    <>
      <Typeahead
        id="basic-example"
        onChange={onChange('basic')}
        options={options}
        placeholder="Choose a state..."
        selected={selected}
      />
      <input
        ref={refHidden}
        style={{ display: 'none' }}
        name="control_Name"
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    </>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<TypeaheadExample />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: my onchange is as follows:`const { values, onChange, onSubmit } = useForm(createPostCallback, {
  value:'',});` how can I modify it to get the actual value?

Comment: Can you please create/update codesandbox?, and how is your onChange method look like?

Comment: @BruceWayne send me the link of  codesandbox, I don't see it on my codesandbox.

Comment: I updated the question,its in the question

Comment: my onchange references a hook: `const onChange = (event) => {
    setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });
  };`

Comment: also usestate in this case only allows the user to add only one value...

Comment: you got the value, you need to find the prop name (event.target.name)

Comment: I updated the answer, now you got both name and value, you need to set your state, basically, we did a curry function here.

Comment: Sam I thank you a lot,but I already have the onchange method which is in another file like this:`const onChange = (event) => {     setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });   };` and then in my post page the onchange is method is called like this:`const { values, onChange, onSubmit } = useForm(createPostCallback, {   value:'',});` shouldnt I just change smth in the second part.I'm afraid it might change the other parts of code

Comment: @BruceWayne I modified the answer with an extra hidden input, now it should work as per your requirement. I also updated the sandbox. Please take a look and let me know.

Comment: thank you for all your effort ,I alredy upvoted your answer .I found a better solution

Answer (score 0):

Unless I misunderstand what you are doing or there is missing code from your example, you want to set the values selected from that component correct?

Looking through the library's examples, it would seem like you don't have the `onChange` prop, where ideally you will set that value. So try this:

```js
<Typeahead
    allowNew
    id="custom-selections-example"
    multiple
    newSelectionPrefix="Add a new item: "
    options={opt}
    placeholder="Autocomplete"
    name="tags" 
    onChange={(value) => console.log('SET VALUE HERE!', value)}
    value={values.options}
    />
```

Edit: take note for form related components in general, chances are you want to do anything relating to setting and storing values within the events (so `onChange` and possible variations of that).

Comment: Hi Juls,I will try it asap I get the opportunity,prb tommorow. Thanks a lot for your answer..will update you on the results

Comment: I just tested and as I thought and had previously tested by adding onChange it gives me this `error:TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined`

Comment: @BruceWayne Are you trying to access the `name` property somewhere? It isn't in your updated code on the original post. Also, what is your `value` within the `onChange` function?

Comment: is in another file like this:`const onChange = (event) => {     setValues({ ...values, [event.target.name]: event.target.value });   };` and then in my post page the onchange is method is called like this:const { values, onChange, onSubmit } = `useForm(createPostCallback, {   value:'',});`

Comment: @BruceWayne It's hard to follow via the comments, so update the post and include all this code with the precise line where things are failing.